# Leer correos librería O365 con python

Tags: python, sql, email

Estoy haciendo una aplicación donde tengo que leer correos de mi bandeja de entrada, Outlook.

Para ello estoy utilizando la librería O365 con python.

La autenticación la hace de forma correcta, luego intento coger la carpeta donde tengo los correos:

```
inbox = mailbox.get_folder(folder_name='Bandeja de entrada')
```

Realizo la query, con el parámetro **created_date_time**:

```
query_email = mailbox.new_query()
query_email = query_email.on_attribute('created_date_time').\
            greater(datetime(from_date_time.year, from_date_time.month, from_date_time.day)).\
            order_by('created_date_time')
```

Y lanzo la query y leo los resultados:

```
for message in inbox.get_messages(limit=999,
                                      query=query_email,
                                      download_attachments=False):
```

Pero el problema está, en que me lee muy pocos o ninguno y solo de la carpeta que le indico al principio.

Lo que quiero que haga es que lea los correos nuevos y viejos, aunque estén ya leídos, desde la fecha que le indico.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para enviar y leer correos puede usar:

- Mail.ReadWrite
- Mail.Send
- User.Read

Necesitas loguearte para obtener el token de acceso que te garantizará utilizar los recursos.

Para autenticarse (iniciar sesión) puede utilizar diferentes interfaces de autenticación. En los siguientes ejemplos, usaremos la interfaz basada en consola, pero puede usar cualquiera.

Al autenticarse en nombre de un usuario:

**Importante:** en caso de que no pueda asegurar el secreto del cliente, puede usar el tipo de flujo de autenticación 'público', que solo requiere la identificación del cliente.

Crea una instancia de un objeto Account con las credenciales (identificación del cliente y secreto del cliente).

Llame account.authenticatey pase los ámbitos que desee (los que agregó anteriormente en el portal de registro de la aplicación).

Nota: cuando utilice la autenticación "en nombre de un usuario", puede pasar los ámbitos al Accountmétodo init o al método de autenticación. De cualquier forma es correcta.

Puede pasar "alcances de protocolo" (como: " https://graph.microsoft.com/Calendars.ReadWrite ") al método o utilizar " ayudantes de alcance " como ("message_all"). Si pasa ámbitos de protocolo, la instancia account debe inicializarse con el mismo protocolo que utilizan los ámbitos. Al usar ayudantes de alcance, puede abstraer el protocolo de los alcances y dejar que esta biblioteca funcione para usted.

Por último, puede mezclar y hacer coincidir "alcances de protocolo" con "ayudantes de alcance". Vaya a la sección de procotol para saber más sobre ellos.

Por ejemplo (siguiendo los permisos anteriores agregados):

```
from O365 import Account
credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph
# the default authentication method will be "on behalf of a user"

account = Account(credentials)
if account.authenticate(scopes=['basic', 'message_all']):
   print('Authenticated!')

# 'basic' adds: 'offline_access' and 'https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read'
# 'message_all' adds: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.ReadWrite' and 'https://graph.microsoft.com/Mail.Send'
```

Cuando se utiliza el método de autenticación "en nombre del usuario", esta llamada al método imprimirá una URL que el usuario debe visitar para dar su consentimiento a la aplicación sobre los permisos requeridos.

A continuación, el usuario debe visitar esta URL y dar su consentimiento a la aplicación. Cuando se da el consentimiento, la página se redireccionará a: " https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/nativeclient " de forma predeterminada (puede cambiar esto) con un parámetro de consulta de URL llamado 'code'.

Luego, el usuario debe copiar la URL de la página resultante y pegarla nuevamente en la consola. El método devolverá True si el intento de inicio de sesión fue exitoso.

Al autenticarse con su propia identidad:

Una instancia de un objeto Account con las credenciales (ID de cliente y el secreto de cliente), especificando el parámetro auth_flow_typede "credenciales" . También debe proporcionar un 'tenant_id'. No es necesario que especifique ningún ámbito.

Llame account.authenticate. Esta llamada le solicitará un token y lo almacenará en el backend. No es necesaria la interacción del usuario. El método almacenará el token en el backend y devolverá True si la autenticación se realizó correctamente.

Por ejemplo:

```
from O365 import Account

credentials = ('my_client_id', 'my_client_secret')

# the default protocol will be Microsoft Graph

account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id='my-tenant-id')
if account.authenticate():
   print('Authenticated!')
```

En este punto, tendrá un token de acceso almacenado que proporcionará credenciales válidas cuando use la API.

El token de acceso solo dura 60 minutos , pero el intento de la aplicación solicitará automáticamente nuevos tokens de acceso.

Cuando se utiliza el método de autenticación "en nombre de un usuario", esto se logra a través de los tokens de actualización (si y solo si agregó el permiso "offline_access"), pero tenga en cuenta que un token de actualización solo dura 90 días. Por lo tanto, debe usarlo antes o deberá solicitar un nuevo token de acceso nuevamente (el usuario no necesita un nuevo consentimiento, solo un inicio de sesión). Si su aplicación necesita funcionar durante más de 90 días sin interacción del usuario y sin interactuar con la API, entonces debe implementar una llamada periódica a Connection.refresh_tokenantes de que hayan pasado los 90 días.

¡Tenga cuidado!: el token de acceso (y actualización) debe permanecer protegido de usuarios no autorizados.

Bajo el método de autenticación "en nombre de un usuario", si cambia el alcance solicitado, el token actual no funcionará y necesitará que el usuario dé su consentimiento nuevamente en la aplicación para obtener acceso a los nuevos alcances solicitados.